# PHP for loop puzzle

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a question.
I am trying to learn PHP and someone told me that doing "star" exercises is a good way to learn loops. 
I got pretty far myself but now I am completely stuck.

Here is my code ;

```
for ($row = 0; $row < 11; $row++)
{
  for($Y = 0; $Y < 1; $Y++){
    echo "Y";                
  }
  for($O = 0; $O < 5; $O++){
    echo "O";
  }
  if ($O <=5) {
    echo "</br>";
  }
}
```

Im trying to print the following to my browser ;

```
Y O O O O O
O Y O O O O
O O Y O O O
O O O Y O O
O O O O Y O
O O O O O Y
O O O O Y O
O O O Y O O
O O Y O O O
O Y O O O O
Y O O O O O
```

I hope you will be able to assist me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what do you have now?

Comment: The "Y" symbol is only on the first place of every row.

Comment: And why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$n=11;


for ($row = 0; $row < $n-1; $row++)
{
  for($line=0; $line < $n;$line++){

  if ($row==$line) {
      echo 'Y';
    }
  else
      echo 'o';}
  echo '</br>';
}
for ($row = $n-1; $row > 0; $row--)
{
  for($line=0; $line < $n;$line++){

  if ($row==$line) {
      echo 'Y';
    }
  else
      echo 'o';}
  echo '</br>';
}
```

It's a start, just follow the matrix horizontally, and whenever you get on the current line you print Y. Then, start from last row towards the start. This will print the two matrices with their diagonals.

It can be optimized with only one loop that goes until the half of $n with forward Y's and then at the second half backwards.